# how to confirm that current git diff is one with current and last and not with current commit and any other

Tags: python, git, git-diff

I am making a tool in python to push and obviously I would want to push the last commit so if I am checking the diff of the last I want to push but if the diff is not of current and last HEAD, then `git push` should not work.

How to check if the `git diff` is between current head and last head i.e. `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` and not any other ?

why I need functionality?

because Diff I am seeing is the diff I am going to send in email. however would that make sense I see a different diff and push the last commit .

which is why I am trying to figure out if diff being displayed is of current and last commit only then i should push else not.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your problem.  Can you rephrase?  Also, a description of *why* you need this functionality would be useful.

Comment: @bluefeet: I have added description , do you understand now ?

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding what you are asking.  It seems like you are questioning the fundamental ability of `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` to give you a diff of `HEAD` against the previous commit (`HEAD^`), which is exactly what it does, and I've got no clue why you think it wouldn't work that way.

Comment: Let me approach my questioning from a different perspective - you are wanting to send an email as a commit is being pushed to an upstream repository, yes?  So, you are wanting to make sure your `git diff` for the email only includes those changes which are *new* with this push, right?  Is that the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: i figured out. using `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` is the diff i want to see and this is the pushed from last committed and emailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sense a simple `git status` or `git diff --cached` would be enough to make sure that the last commit is indeed the last one, meaning there is no work in progress, some of it already added to the index, which could constitute a new commit.

If `git status` doesn't mention any file added to the index, then you can push your last commit.